# Convert .svg to extremely large .bmp in Python

Tags: python, image, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

We have a laser writer in our lab that takes in black and white .bmp images and use those to determine what spots on a plane will be illuminated by a laser. Each pixel is a fixed unit of area, and in order for the total write to be the size we need, we need a .bmp that's about 50,000x50,000 pixels.

We need to generate those .bmp files from .svg files. I have python code that can do that for relatively small images

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg(outfile + '.svg')
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, outfile + '.bmp', fmt='BMP')
```

but when trying to create one of our needed large images, Python runs out of memory and crashes on a 32GB memory computer. Are there any libraries that are designed to be extremely memory efficient for such tasks? Or are there significant optimizations available with the current libraries?

Comment: Just to be sure: You run a 64bit variant of Python?

Comment: @MichaelButscher According to this [this method](https://www.scivision.dev/python-check-32-64-bit/), yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ImageMagick, which will cache sections of extremely large images to disk to keep from running out of memory. A command prompt tool and a Python wrapper for the tool exist.

Comment: for anyone wondering; [`wand`](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/) is one such ImageMagick python binding